# Creating a custom date filter in Hot Chocolate

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I've been trying and failing to create a custom filter for `Date` types using Hot Chocolate. The issue is that the HC defaults to `DateTimeOffset`, but for filtering dates coming from the application, the time portion doesn't make any sense.  I've tried to create a custom filter type, but I'm running into the issue that in the model that is being filtered, the date fields are all nullable. So the following code throws an exception.

```cs
public class QueryableDateLessThanEqualToHandler : QueryableComparableLowerThanOrEqualsHandler
{
    public QueryableDateTimeLessThanOrEqualToFilter(ITypeConverter typeConverter, InputParser inputParser) : base(typeConverter,inputParser)
    {
    }

    private static readonly MethodInfo _toShortDateString = typeOf(DateTime)
        .GetMethods()
        .Single(x => x.Name == nameof(DateTime.ToShortDateString);

    protected override int Operation => DefaultFilterOperations.LowerThanOrEquals;

    public override Expression HandleOperation(
        QueryableFIlterContext context,
        IFilterOperationField field,
        IValueNode value,
        object? parsedValue)
    {
        try
        {
            Expression property = context.GetInstance();
       
            if(parsedValue is DateTimeOffset inputDateTimeOffset)
            {
                DateTime filterDate = inputDateTimeOffset.DateTime;

                return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
                    Expression.Call(property, _toShortDateString),
                    Expression.Constant(filterDate.ToShortDateString()));
            }
            else if(parsedValue is DateTime inputDateTime) //I have both datetimeoffset and datetime in the model I'm filtering
            {
                return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
                    Expression.Call(property, _toShortDateString),
                    Expression.Constant(inputDateTime.ToShortDateString()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.message);
             return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
                 Expression.Constant(0),Expression.Constant(1));
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I'm getting is `Method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' declared on type 'System.DateTime' cannot be called with stance of type 'System.Nullable'1[System.DateTimeOffset]'`

I believe I understand why I'm getting this error, because the acutal field that is being filtered is a nullable DatetimeOffset, but I have no idea how to convert it to a not nullable field in this context.

I have a feeling it is somewhere in the `_toShortDateString`, but how to do that has so far alluded me.

This feels like it should be straight forward, but at this point I'm totally lost.

Any help would be appreciated.